# Doctrine2 / Symfony 2 @ParamConverter with custom repository method dropping unmapped arguments

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, mapping

i am in the need to send a non-mapped argument to my custom repository method.
However it seems those arguments are purely ignored, I don't get them when I vardump my repository method arguments.

I have found the issue detailed here but without comments : @ParamConverter with custom repository method dropping unmapped arguments

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

The example in my case :

```
* @Route("/edit_planning/{planning}/{onlyPending}", name="edit_planning", defaults={"onlyPending": false})
* @ParamConverter("planning", class="AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Planning", options={"mapping" : {"planning" = "id", "onlyPending"="onlyPending"}, "repository_method" = "findPlanningDependingOnExecution"})
public function editPlanningAction(Request $request, Planning $planning)
```

OnlyPending route parameter is not passed to the repository method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try this: (broke into miltiple lines for readability)

```
@ParamConverter("planning",
    class="AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Planning", 
    options = {
        "id": {"planning", "onlyPending"}, 
        "repository_method" = "findPlanningDependingOnExecution"
    }
)
```

You are not changing the `mapping` but rather the definition of "id". Then `findPlanningDependingOnExecution` will receive the `array` parameter with keys `planning` and `onlyPending`.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: yes, it's working! could be nice of the team to implement something cleaner